# Cannot update textbox vb.net -crossthreading

Tags: vb.net, textbox, console

I am trying to make an application to run multiple (adb specially) commands and get the output and display in a label.

First of all, i need to start the process to execute the commands. Thanks to stackoverflow and @pasty I found this (second reply): [How to get Output of a Command Prompt Window line by line in Visual Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347823/how-to-get-output-of-a-command-prompt-window-line-by-line-in-visual-basic)

Well, i thought that because it outputted to the console, it would be simple to just write it to the label. BIG MISTAKE! It gives me a cross threading error!
A little bit of googling and stack overflow I found this: [vb.net accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858557/vb-net-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-thread-it-was-created-on)

Well, i tried to implement that, but the program just <s>crashes</s> freezes.

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' store error output lines

    Dim executable As String() = {"adb", "adb"}
    Dim arguments As String() = {"help", "reboot"}
    For i As Integer = 0 To 0
        Dim process = New Process()
        process.StartInfo = createStartInfo(executable(i), arguments(i))
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        AddHandler process.Exited, Sub(ByVal sendera As Object, ByVal ea As System.EventArgs)
                                       Console.WriteLine(process.ExitTime)
                                       Console.WriteLine(". Processing done.")
                                       'UpdateTextBox(ea)

                                   End Sub
        ' catch standard output
        AddHandler process.OutputDataReceived, Sub(ByVal senderb As Object, ByVal eb As DataReceivedEventArgs)
                                                   If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(eb.Data)) Then
                                                       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}> {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"), eb.Data))
                                                       'UpdateTextBox(eb.Data)

                                                   End If
                                               End Sub
        ' catch errors
        AddHandler process.ErrorDataReceived, Sub(ByVal senderc As Object, ByVal ec As DataReceivedEventArgs)
                                                  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("! {0}", ec.Data))
                                                  Dim a As String = String.Format("! {0}", ec.Data)
                                                  'UpdateTextBox(a)
                                              End Sub
        ' start process
        Dim result = process.Start()
        ' and wait for output
        process.BeginOutputReadLine()
        ' and wait for errors :-)
        process.BeginErrorReadLine()
        process.WaitForExit()

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTextBox(ByVal a As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim args() As String = {a}
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf UpdateTextBox), args)
        Return
    End If
    Label1.Text += "a"
End Sub

Private Function createStartInfo(ByVal executable As String, ByVal arguments As String) As ProcessStartInfo
    Dim processStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(executable, arguments)
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executable)
    ' we want to read standard output
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    ' we want to read the standard error
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = False
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Return processStartInfo

End Function
```

And the source code: https://github.com/iAmAOpenSource/SyncfusionWindowsFormsApplication3

Comment: `the program just crashes` Are you debugging, and you get an error message? Or what?

Comment: @djv It just freezes. Should have reworded it better :). No output or anything. Need to learn debugging in visual studio. Still have a long way to go

Comment: My guess is that the call to `process.WaitForExit()` is blocking the UI thread until the process ends, and when you get a line of output in the `process.OutputDataReceived` you are calling `Me.Invoke`, which tries to run code on the UI thread, which is blocked, so... freeze.  You probably need to move the logic that starts the processes onto a different thread - maybe just wrap the contents of `Button1_Click` in `Task.Run`.

Comment: You should start by debugging your program - step through it line by line. Put a breakpoint inside the `Button1_Click` handler, and "step over" each line. One of these lines most likely won't grant you control of the program anymore; this line would be the culprit. I suspect @Mark is right. Unfortunately we can't debug *for* you, so try it and we can help you make sense of things.

Comment: @djv @Mark you lot were right! it was the `process.WaitForExit()` line that was blocking the thread. The `task.run(Sub() NameOfTheSub())` works perfectly. Thank you very much!!!! Do any of you want to post the answer so  I can tick as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `process.WaitForExit()` will block the UI thread until the spawned process exits, but while processing the output in the `process.OutputDataReceived` event you are calling `Me.Invoke` which tries to run the code on the UI thread, which is blocked, so the program freezes.  You could move the logic in `Button1_Click` onto another thread, e.g.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Task.Run(
        Sub()
            ... current logic
        End Sub
    )
End Sub
```

That way the UI thread won't be blocked and the `Me.Invoke` call won't cause a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you very much. Still had a little problem because the `textbox` was not being accepted as a argument for the function `UpdateTextBox`, although i resolved it by using a global variable to store which textbox to output it to(i know i should not be doing this, but it works so :)).